# When to use Threadpool in Gevent

Tags: python, threadpool, gevent

I've noticed that Gevent has threadpool object.
Can someone explain to me when to use threadpool and when to use regular pool? Whats the difference between gevent.threadpool and gevent.pool?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you have a piece of python code that takes a long time to run (for seconds) and does not cause switching of greenlets, all other greenlets / gevent jobs will 'starve' and have no computation time and it will look like your application 'hangs'.

If you put this 'heavy' task in a Threadpool, the threaded execution will make sure other greenlets will not starve. But I believe if your code spends a lot of time in a C library, it will have no effect.

Below is an example from [gevent](https://github.com/surfly/gevent/blob/master/examples/threadpool.py). Note that the example uses `time.sleep` which blocks, instead of `gevent.sleep`.

**TIP**:
If you have a loop that takes a long time to run, then you can just put in a gevent.sleep(0) in the loop. Every loop other greenlets will have a chance to run. The **gevent**.sleep(0) in your slow loop will make sure other greenlets will not starve and the application appears responsive

```
import time
import gevent
from gevent.threadpool import ThreadPool


pool = ThreadPool(3)
start = time.time()
for _ in xrange(4):
    pool.spawn(time.sleep, 1)
gevent.wait()
delay = time.time() - start
print 'Running "time.sleep(1)" 4 times with 3 threads. Should take about 2 seconds: %.3fs' % delay
```

Comment: "But I believe if your code spends a lot of time in a c library it will have no effect" are you sure? Are you referring to C extensions or the `ctypes`? Because if you release the GIL (manually in a C extension or automatically as `ctypes` does) then the application will benefit from the ThreadPool, wouldn't it?

Comment: yes. "if you release the GIL" exactly. I don't have time to figure that out of every C libary...